# How to choose the fields from a associated model at find

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Before I had this:

```
//ArticlesController::index
$articles = $this->Articles->find('all', [
  'contain' => ['Comments']
]);
```

So I set the `fields key`:

```
//ArticlesController::index
$articles = $this->Articles->find('all', [
  'fields' => ['title', 'text],
  'contain' => ['Comments']
]);
```

Since I set the `fields key` the result of the `find` is not bringing the `comments` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$articles = $this->Articles->find('all')
        ->select(['fields_you_want_from_Articles'])
        ->contain(['Comments'  => function($q) {
            return $q
                ->select(['fields_you_want_from_Comments']);
        }]);
```